# How to setup SSL certificate for A Record subdomain pointing to another server IP address

Tags: ssl, encryption, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am new to SSL certificate encryption and will appreciate any advice that will help me to get the job done. Here is the case:

I own a domain `domain.com` and need to create a subdomain `sub.domain.com` that points to my server IP address (I host the server). I do this by creating an A record for `sub.domain.com` and set it to point to IP `xx.xx.xx.xx`.

Now I need to secure `sub.domain.com` so that when users access it, it is SSL encrypted: `https://sub.domain.com`

How should I approach this?

It seems that the domain hosting company cannot issue an SSL certificate for A Record but only for subdomain account, which I do not wish to use.

Since the A record points to a server hosted by me, should I create a certificate for this particular server? 
If so, how do I create such universally trusted certificate and not just one valid for localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A certificate need to be issued for the domain in the URL. This means if you want to secure `https://sub.example.com` then you need a certificate for `sub.example.com`, no matter if `sub.example.com` is a CNAME to some other domain or if the A record points to a specific IP address. A certificate for an IP address is only needed if you want to secure the (rare case) of `https://ip-address/`.

If you want to secure a server which is fully in your own control you can have the A record point to it and then get a certificate for the specific subdomain. For example [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) provides free certificates and there are tons of instructions online how to use these with a specific server setup.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it and the problem was I could not get an SSL certificate for a subdomain with A record from the domain hosting company. How about the local server, do I need a certificate for it if I want to send emails from it via SSL SMTP? Currently, if I try to do that I get `handshake_failure - SSLHandshakeException` error which makes me think the SMTP server does not accept the connection from unverified source. What do you think?

Comment: @BradG: Regarding SMTP - this is a different question and should not be asked in a comment. But there is almost never a local SSL certificate needed to send a mail.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Steffen. Indeed it is a different question but still somewhat related to the topic since I had to copy over the SSL certificate for the domain to the local server and add it in apache config -> Therefore, I was wondering whether it has any role in validating requests towards the SMTP server.

Comment: @BradG: what you configure in Apache is not related at all to validating requests to the SMTP server.